# Power off discrete GPU when not in use to save power

Tags: linux, graphics-card, power, gpu

I am trying to setup a virtual Windows system on Arch Linux using VGA passthrough. One issue with this I see is that the GPU will just idle 24/7 using a large chunk of overall power for no good reason.

Is it at all possible to power off or put the GPU into super low power mode when no video output is needed? I would prefer for the virtual Windows system to be running but perhaps I could start it on demand if needed if it can be put to sleep easier from Linux.

I am considering using high end Nvidia card but would consider going with Radeon if Nvidia cards cannot be put to sleep as well.